# Как в адроид проект подключить Google и Firebase аналитику?

Tags: android, google-analytics, firebaseanalytics

Как в `Android-проект` подключить `Google` и `Firebase` аналитику? Проблема заключается в том, что `Google` выдает свой `Json`-файл, а `Firebase` свой. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: google analitycs старый формат, используйте firebase

Comment: @iFr0z это уже дело вкусов, `Firebase` может собирать аналитику из `Google Analytics` (интерфейс которого по крайней мне больше нравится). Заявления об отказе от `Google Analytics` в сторону `Firebase` ещё не было, поэтому можно спокойно использовать "старый формат".

Comment: @zTrap согласен, грубо написал совет, но мне кажется так лучше, лишь потому, что рано или поздно придется)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это один и тот же `Json`-файл, только с дополнительными параметрами (откройте и сравните). После подключения тех или иных SDK к проекту `Json`-файл, получаемый на разных страницах (страницах подключения SDK) приобретает общий вид (везде одинаковый). Логичнее всего использовать файл конфигурации последней версии (сразу после подключения того или иного SDK)